# Import a single row from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-online, excel

I'm currently trying to copy a single column from an excel sheet and import it in an existing list on sharepoint. I tried this via microsoft access, but i'm only allowed 255 characters per row!
Is there any other way to do this? I need more space!

Answer (score 1):

Problem isn't the way you are importing excel sheet into SharePoint list, I think problem is with SharePoint list as I assume you are using default columns for importing data that is larger then 255 characters which is not supported by default.

Just use column type note and you will have more space.
Looks like this is issue that SPFieldText won't allow more than 255 chars, althought it has [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtext.maxlength.aspx) property, it anyway won't allow more chars.

You may read [this article](http://panvega.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/sp-field-types-with-more-than-255-characters/) on how to create your custom column that can be used to type in more than 255 chars.

[Helpful Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987104/modify-site-columntype-text-to-allow-more-than-255-characters/2987426#2987426)

Answer (score 0):

So is the question how to import a cell with more than 255 characters in it, 
into a SharePoint List column? 
Or is the question how to restore the Excel Sync feature in Excel 2007/2010? Anyhow give this a try.

Methods:

1. Microsoft Excel Add-in

   - [Download the Excel Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636%28office.11%29.aspx) (SynchronizeWSSandExcel)
   - Enable the Addin
   - Open your Sharepoint List in Excel
   - Then simply right-click on the list and select Synchronize with Sharepoint.
2. Update in Access linked to SharePoint List
3. [SP Lists and text fields with more than 255 characters see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987104/modify-site-columntype-text-to-allow-more-than-255-characters)

   - Unfortunately this doesn't sounds like an easy fix.

SharePoint lists use datatypes in each column of the data.

Instructions on [exporting Excel table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-an-excel-table-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA010131472.aspx) to SharePoint list.

See also: [Restoring Two-Way Synchronization on SharePoint Lists Using Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134054/Restoring-Two-Way-Synchronization-on-SharePoint-Li)